# Old transformer input output

Tags: transformer, pinout

I have a transformer found on my old computer ups.
I dont understand its pin out. It has black and red lead one side. And on adjacent side it has four wires connected with a female connector.
I want to make a bench power supply for my lab with it.
[image: old ups transformer]

Comment: Your best bet is to plug it in and test each wire with a multimeter. Specifically, test the voltage between each of the wires.

Comment: I recommend you to use an LCR meter to find the windings. Note that number of turns is proportional to the inductances. That's a way to find voltage ratings. But for current, you'll need to know wire diameters which is not easy to measure.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I want voltage ratings

Comment: Find an LCR meter and measure inductances between each leg. The winding with the highest inductance should be 220V or 110V side. Voltage ratios come from number of turns which can be calculated from \$L = A_L \cdot N^2\$ (\$A_L\$ is the same for all windings).

Comment: So there is no easy way to find out its pinout. Its manufacturer is Intex.

Comment: be aware that this transformer probably does not provide safety isolation, so to be safe one output terminal of your completed powerssuply must be connected to safety ground.

Comment: http://aboutintex.blogspot.ca/p/ups.html  5V output on 1 pair.

Comment: Throw it away anf buy a new one - this one looks properly worn out. Safety first.

Comment: @Jasen you mean earthing?

Comment: @Andyaka how did you understand it is worn out

Comment: The laminations are rusting on the outside faces.

Comment: Another important point (when salvaging like this) is to make sure the secondary windings are rated for the maximum current you intend to draw.  You can get some idea of this by looking at the wire gauge and resistance measurements.

Comment: @Andyaka There are so many transformers rusting on the iron band and still running properly. LOL

Comment: @AvijitPalit yes, earthing.

Comment: rust is not usually problematic, it just means the varnish on the lamination has been breached. big lumps of steel will attract condensation and go rusty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this transformer is from a UPS it will be used as both a step-down transformer for charging the battery, and a step-up transformer to generate 230Vac from the battery voltage. Because of this it is wrong to refer to the windings as primary and secondary, it is probably better to refer to them as high and low voltage windings.

Most small UPS transformers have 3 windings:

1. High voltage winding.
2. Low voltage winding. Typically around 12Vac
3. A sense winding. Typically around 3Vac but with little power available.

The 2 separate wires probably connect to the low voltage winding since they have high current ring crimp terminals on them. 2 of the wires in the connector will be the 230Vac winding, and the other 2 wires will be the "sense" winding so the UPS can sense the voltage it is generating. It's not possible to guess which is which.

Since the transformer is made by Intex it probably comes from an Intex UPS. You may be able to work out which wires are mains and which are sense wires by getting a circuit diagram of the UPS.

Comment: I thought the black and red wires are for main 230v

Comment: Where do I get diagram for this kind of transformer.

Comment: You'll have to search for "Intex UPS XXX circuit diagram" where XXX is the model number of the UPS. I found this one [here](http://aboutintex.blogspot.co.uk/2015/02/ups-800va-circuit-diagram.html) although its probably not the same as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Avijit, I believe that female connector is your secondary windings while the 2 wires are primary winding which gets connected to mains supply.
Using multimeter, check the wires. If red and black are connected, they should be primary and in that case Red means live and black is neutral.
On female connector you may find a single winding with taps, so all wires will be connected. other option is there will be 2 secondary windings and you will find continuity between first 2 and last 2 pins. 
I guess the primary winding should show higher resistance value than secondary if its a step down transformer

Comment: A word of caution: DONT connect to mains unless you are absolutely sure, else you will burn it. Check the original case and wiring which can confirm if the 2 wires are for mains

Comment: on the other hand the 4-wire connector could be for mains (allowing AVR operation) and the 2 loose wires for low voltage.

Comment: @Sudhir the black and red wires is not main

Comment: @Avijit: that was a suggestion I gave, I also added a comment to check the original casing and wiring to confirm.